# htaccess rewriterule with multiple GET values

Tags: .htaccess

I want to use a RewriteRule to clean up my URL, i need the rewrite to allow multiple different `$_GET` values, but they need to sometimes be empty, without causing an error.

currently what I have tried is (located in .htaccess):

```
RewriteRule ^people/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /people.php?alid=$1&alb=$2&albb=$3
```

This works great, so long that the url has all three slashes present, for example `http://www.example.com/people/1/2/3` works great.

However if I use the URL `http://www.example.com/people/1` the result is a 404 error which is what i need to prevent from occuring.

Is there a possible way to fix this, so i can have URLs without all three `/`'s and not receive a 404 error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try ^people(/([^/]+))*

You'll need to change the numbers, as there is an extra set of parenthesis in my expression.

[^/]+ matches everything that is not a /
the / at the beginning will match a /
and its in brackets and with a * at the end so you can have (/something) 0 or more times.